# Changing font-family with jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

without jq it works
http://jsfiddle.net/AaT9b/17/

and with it doesn't
http://jsfiddle.net/AaT9b/16/

can this only be changed by adding a new theme with themeroller ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css CSS includes this:

```
.ui-body-c, .ui-body-c input, .ui-body-c select, .ui-body-c textarea, .ui-body-c button {
    font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}
```

That is over writing your inline css.

So if you give you inline style higher importance, it will work:

```
body .ui-body-c{
    font-family:"Lucida Grande";
    font-size:200%;
}
```

See - http://jsfiddle.net/AaT9b/19/

Comment: +1 for being a better answer. You're right, !important probably isn't the best way to do this.

Comment: do i alwyas have to look up the name of elements from the jquery css ? or is there a option that my css has always an higher importance ?

Comment: Im not massively familure with jquery mobile css, so couldn't say for sure. if you were to give an element a class, it should be fine. body is quite a generic selector.