# Jquery Mobile - taking the font of mobile

Tags: android, jquery, jsp

I had created few JSP's using Mobile Jquery.

I had used 'Verdena' as my font in all the JSP's.
If i access the jsp in mobile,it takes the font style of the mobile instead of my default font.

How to handle this??

Answer (score 0):

Jquery Mobile reformats your content, adding inner divs and whatnot, and applies its own styling. You'll have to look deep into the CSS using firebug or web inspector to see where you want to override it, and how.

The JQM CSS gets quite specific with its styling rules, so you'll have to either edit the JQM stylesheets or get even more specific with your rules (or the JQM will have precedence even though they're listed first). You can also add !important as a possible workaround.

This other answer lists more specific CSS you can try:

[Changing font-family with jquery mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807441/changing-font-family-with-jquery-mobile)